# Nodemailer with html doesn't work but with text it's ok

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm facing a very strange problem, and I will go straight to the point.
Everything works great on my own computer, but I have to comment the html in mail options to get it works on my VPS hosted by OVH.com. I tried with port 467 and secure true, but the behaviour is exactly the same.

Here is my code :

```
const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "ssl0.ovh.net",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: serverParams.mail.username,
        pass: serverParams.mail.password
    }
});

mailer.sendMail({
   from: 'noreply@mydomain.com',
   to: "mymailaddress@gmail.com",
   subject: 'Hello world',
   text: 'Hello word',
   html: '<p><b>Hello word</b></p>',
}, (err, res) => {
   console.log("Mail response: " + res.response);
});
```

Does someone has an idea ? I can't reach ovh support at this time.

Here is what i get from the mailer:

```
Mail response: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2A8781AEE4289
```

Comment: Any error thrown? What is the response of your request ...

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add it. I edited the main message.

Comment: So you have an smtp server running on your vps? seems that this smtp server accepts the mail for further processing. Anything in the smtp server's logs?

Comment: No, i'm using OVH's one at ssl0.ovh.net. I don't have any smtp server on my VPS nor my own computer.

Comment: so what happens, if you try to send an html body? doesn't work is not a very good error description

Comment: That's the question, i don't really know how emails work. From my side, everything looks the same. I have exactly the same behavior on my server with or without html. However, if i set a html key in the mail option, the mail is not received (only from my VPS).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228423/discussion-between-holgrabus-and-derpirscher).